# Aframe: is it possible to disable logging of version

Tags: aframe

The a-frame library always logs some information, like the version it is and the three.js version. Is there an easy way to disable this logging?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Would have to fork A-Frame, remove the logs from src/index.js, and build a dist manually (npm run dist).

Answer (score 0):

See [ngokevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5965986/ngokevin)'s answer. If you want to disable it completely (including your own console.logs):

```
var oldLog = console.log; // also check console.info etc..
console.log = function() {}; // override 
... // load initial stuff 
console.log = oldLog; // to bring it back if you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out content you don't want to show :

```
var oldLog = console.log; // also check console.info etc..
console.log = function(...args) {
  for (let part of args)
    if (part.match("A-Frame")) return
  oldLog(args)    
}; // override
```

This isn't perfect (loses some data and coloring) but shows the idea.